# PHP, Only select logged in username from database

Tags: php, html, web

I basically want it to select only the current user thats logged in and then display there username and points instead it displays ALL users in the database

This is the code that displays it

```
    <?php
include("connect.php"); // Includes the file connect.php to connect to database
session_start(); // Starting session cookies
if($_SESSION['LOGGEDIN'] == 1)  //Checking if they have the session cookie
{


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userdata");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Username</th>
<th>Points</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['points'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
}

else
{
    echo "<title>Error!</title>";
    //Doesn't have session cookie
    echo "YOU ARE NOT LOGGED IN!";
}
?>
```

Comment: where is `where` clause in your query..

Comment: I guess that's the problem.. What would I put to select the current logged in user?

Comment: `where username = '$_SESSION["LOGGEDIN"]'`

Comment: when I put this and it showed nothing this time.

Comment: show me your table structure and tell me what are you storing into your session variable?

Comment: He's storing a 1 if they logged in successfully into his session variable, which is the problem, as I noted in my answer. He needs to store the username in that variable so he can check it with the database.

Comment: @David - agree. you answer is absolutely correct i know. but i was just trying to let him understand :)

Answer (score 4):

Well you are selecting the entire table.

Simply change it to

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `userdata` WHERE `username`='".$_SESSION["LOGGEDIN"]."' LIMIT 1");
```

Note that you should change your session variable `LOGGEDIN` to contain the username of the logged in user, or use another session variable and replace my reference to `LOGGEDIN` in my above line of code.

For instance, in your login script, rather than doing something like this:

```
if($_POST["user"] == $user and $_POST["password"] == $pass)
$_SESSION["LOGGEDIN"] = 1;
```

Do this:

```
if($_POST["user"] == $user and $_POST["password"] == $pass)
$_SESSION["LOGGEDIN"] = $user;
```

If you do use `LOGGEDIN`, you will need to update your initial if clause so that it doesn't check to see if it equals one, but instead checks if it is set:

```
if(isset($_SESSION["LOGGEDIN"]))
```

So your file should look something like this:

```
<?php
include("connect.php"); // Includes the file connect.php to connect to database
session_start(); // Starting session cookies
if(isset($_SESSION['LOGGEDIN']))  //Checking if they have the session cookie
{


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `userdata` WHERE `username`='".$_SESSION["LOGGEDIN"]."' LIMIT 1");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Username</th>
<th>Points</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['points'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
}

else
{
    echo "<title>Error!</title>";
    //Doesn't have session cookie
    echo "YOU ARE NOT LOGGED IN!";
}
?>
```

Comment: Did you do what I noted below my first line of code? You need to make `$_SESSION["LOGGEDIN"]` store your user's username or it will not work, and you also need to change your if statement to the one I supplied.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

        include("connect.php");
        $email= $_POST['userid'];
        $password= $_POST['password1']; 
        $papas=base64_encode($password);
        $check = $_POST['rememberme'];      
            $tablename="userdata";
        $select_qry = $jeob->SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM ".$jeob->dbprefix.$tablename." WHERE email ='$email' AND password ='$papas' AND active_link='1' ");
            if($jeob->SqlRows($select_qry) == "0"){                 
             echo "Invalid Username and Password";
            } else {

            $getuser = $jeob->SqlFetch($select_qry);
            $_SESSION['userid'] = $getuser['user_id'];  
            $_SESSION['oauth_provider'] = "normal";
            $_SESSION['email'] = $getuser['email']; 
            }
                if($_SESSION['userid'] == ""
                {
                echo "You are not logged in";
                }
                else
                {
                Welcome "Fetch username using the session id or emial"
                }
    ?>
```

Hope this is useful to you